# how do i create a dummy variable for the whole dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe full of randomly generated numbers from -100 to 100, 10 columns by 10 rows. I want to create a dummy variable so that it will create a new column and if the value in any column or row is greater than 50 this is represented by 1, and if not then it is 0. How would I do this?

This is my code for the dataframe below.

`df<- matrix(-100:100, ncol=10, nrow=10)`

How would i use mutate or any other way so that I can create this dummy column?

Answer (score 0):

please note that creating a dummy variable for colMeans only makes sense if you have a symmetric dataframe/matrix.

```r
library(tidyvese)

# set seed for reproducibility
seed(41) 

# create the dataframe.
# please note that in your example you produced a matrix not a dataframe

df <- matrix(sample(0:100, 100, replace = T), ncol=10, nrow=10) %>% as.data.frame()


#use dplyr::mutate to create the dummy variables using base::rowMeans and base::colMeans

df <- df %>% mutate(dummy_rows = ifelse(rowMeans(df) >50, 1,0),
                    dummy_cols = ifelse(colMeans(df) >50, 1,0))
```